# how to stop printing repeated values in this code

Tags: python, opencv

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from pyzbar import pyzbar


def read_barcodes(frame):
    processed =[]
    barcodes = pyzbar.decode(frame)
    for barcode in barcodes:
        
        x, y , w, h = barcode.rect
       
        barcode_info = barcode.data.decode('utf-8')
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y),(x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        
       
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX
        cv2.putText(frame, barcode_info, (x + 6, y - 6), font, 2.0, (255, 255, 255), 1)
        
        #my_list = [barcode_info]
        #myFinalList = np.unique(my_list).tolist()
        #print(myFinalList)

        #print(barcode_info)
        
       
        with open("barcode_result.txt", mode ='w') as file:
            file.write("Recognized Barcode:" + barcode_info)
    return frame
    
def main():
   
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    ret, frame = camera.read()
    
    while ret:
        ret, frame = camera.read()
        frame = read_barcodes(frame)
        cv2.imshow('Barcode/QR code reader', frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27:
            break
    
    camera.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

how to break the loop from printing the repeating values

Comment: you mean it is reading the same barcode data continuously and you wanna avoid it ?

Comment: yes Mr.Yunus I want to avoid reading of same barcode data continuously

Comment: Contact author https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-barcode-qr-code-reader-using-python-360e22dfb6e5